# MS-Access get error message when calling Qualtrics API run-time error 449 Argument Not Optional

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, httprequest, qualtrics

I'm new to Access and currently work as a data system manager at an HIV research lab. We use Qualtrics to create surveys for participants to take online, and we use Access to call Qualtrics API to add participants to Qualtrics contact panel, automatically generate survey links for them, email survey distribution links to the participants, and store their responses through exported files.

Here is the link to the Qualtrics API documentation: 
https://api.qualtrics.com/

I'm migrating all the Qualtrics function to v3, and run into this run-time argument not optional error when trying to generate survey distribution links for participants & send them emails with their survey links.

Here is the API documentation link to the Qualtrics function I'm working on - CreateSurveyDistributionLinks:

https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#distribution-create-1

https://api.qualtrics.com/reference#email-mailing-list

The following shows my code:

```
Public Function createSurveyDistributionLinks(strSubject As String, _
     strMessageID As String, strRecipients As String, strSurveyID As String, _
     dtSendDate As Date, dtExpirationDate As Date)

'note: this function does not contain message feature as it is not 
'  used in 1KS. Can add for other uses by including a dicMessage object
Dim strURL As String
Dim JSON As Object
Dim dicMessage As Dictionary
Dim dicHeader As Dictionary
Dim strBodyJson As String
Dim strFromEmail As String
Dim strFromName As String


    Me.initObject
    strURL = "https://az1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/distributions"

    strFromEmail = "day2day%40chestnyc.org"
    strFromName = "day2day"
    strFromName = Replace(strFromName, " ", "%20") 'Convert spaces
    strSubject = Replace(strSubject, " ", "%20") 'Convert spaces


    Set dicHeader = New Dictionary

    dicHeader("fromEmail") = strFromEmail
    dicHeader("fromName") = strFromName
    dicHeader("subject") = strSubject

    Set dicMessage = New Dictionary
    dicMessage("messageId") = strMessageID
    dicMessage("libraryId") = strLibID

    dicMessage("header") = dicHeader


    Set dicBody = New Dictionary
    dicBody("recipients") = strRecipients
    dicBody("surveyId") = strSurveyID
    dicBody("sendDate") = formatQualtricsTimes(dtSendDate)
    dicBody("expirationDate") = formatQualtricsTimes(Nz(dtExpirationDate, "2050-01-01 00:00:00"))
    dicBody("message") = dicMessage

    strBodyJson = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(dicBody)
    Debug.Print strBodyJson

    With xmlhttprequester
        .Open "POST", strURL
        .setRequestHeader "X-API-TOKEN", strToken
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .send strBodyJson

        .waitForResponse
        If InStr(.responseText, "EMD_") > 0 Then
            'it worked!
            Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
            Dim strrand As String
            createSurveyDistributionLinks = JSON("result")("id")
            Debug.Print JSON("result")("id")
        Else
            Debug.Print "an error has occurred" & vbNewLine & .responseText
            createSurveyDistributionLinks = "false"
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Here's the line where I encountered the run-time error:

```
 strDistributionID = oQual.createSurveyDistributionLinks(strSubject, _
    strMessageID, strRecipientID, strSurveyID, CStr(dtExpTime), CStr(dtTime))
```

I would truly appreciate all your insights, really hope my code works!!

Best,
Jess

Comment: Check your VBA options and make sure you have "Break in class module" checked in your error handling settings. Why are you using CStr() when calling your function - don't the last two parameters expect dates as arguments?

Comment: Hi Tim thank you for your reply! I've removed the Cstr() and still have the same issue tho

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested in your error handling settings?  Are all of the arguments you're passing populated with values?  Your function has 6 parameters and you're passing the same number of arguments, so it's difficult to see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Tim, I did change the error handling settings and put stop signs on each line of code, the same error pops up but now on this line: dicMessage("header") = dicHeader"

Answer (score 1):

When working with custom classes in VBA you need to make sure you have your VBA error handling set to "Break in class module" or you will not see the underlying error in your class instance (you only get an error at the entry point - in this case the line which calls `oQual.createSurveyDistributionLinks`).

Your code should should include `Set` when assigning an object-type variable to a dictionary:

```
Set dicMessage("header") = dicHeader 

Set dicBody("message") = dicMessage
```